# Another problem installing Asterisk on kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, asterisk, voip

I am trying to install Asterisk [version 13] on Kali linux.

I first install DAHDI, but I won't install libPRI.

So when I install asterisk,  I use:

```
./configure
```

and

```
make menuselect
```

Till now it's ok! But when I put:

```
make install
```

I get this message

```
...
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:430:3: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:430:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘param’) [enabled by default]
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:431:3: error: field name not in record or union initializer
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:431:3: error: (near initialization for ‘param’)
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:431:3: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:431:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘param’) [enabled by default]
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:439:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:449:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pjsip_rx_data_free_cloned’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
make[1]: *** [res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.o] Error 1
make: *** [res] Error 2
```

can any one help me ?

Comment: Asterisk which version?

Comment: @kira asterisk 13

Comment: Have you downloaded it from the official site?

Comment: @kira yes ! from http://www.asterisk.org/downloads

Comment: can suggest do make menuconfig, turn off chan_pjsip, turn on chan_sip for now.